# RxJs map function causes upstream observable to be called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am a bit new to RxJS and am having problems with `map` on an Observable which causes the upstream Observable being called multiple times (i.e. an HTTP request).

I have the following example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-uxygsb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

the gist is the following

```
function simulateHttp(val: any, delay:number) {
    return Observable.of(val)
        .delay(delay);
}

function timeLog(msg) {
    console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()}:  ${msg}`);   
}

const timerStream: Observable<number> = IntervalObservable
  .create(8000)
const manualRefreshStream = new Subject<any>();
const combinedTriggerStream: Observable<any> = Observable.merge(timerStream, manualRefreshStream);

const httpResultStream = combinedTriggerStream.switchMap(v => {
  return simulateHttp('http ' + v, 3000);
});
const dataStream = httpResultStream
  .map(v => `*${v}*`)
  .map(v => `#${v}#`);
```

Basically as soon as I do a transformation via `map` on the `httpResult` stream I get the `simulateHttp` method being called multiple times.

I googled around and it seems that `share` might be the solution but I am not versed well enough to understand where to put it and *why*.

Comment: `map` itself doesn't make multiple subscriptions but you're using `logSubscribe` so many times in your example that it's hard to tell where the subscriptions come from. Maybe try using `do` to log what's going on in your streams and you'll avoid side-effects of multiple subscriptions.

Comment: @martin, I tried the example in multiple iterations. The problems only start as soon as I do `map` on the httpResultStream. If I dont, then I only get a single invocation.

Comment: @martin, thanks for the info, my attempt with removing the `map` operators did indeed show that the root cause was the multiple subscribers on the "cold" observable. Together with the info from @Jeto I think I finally understand whats going on. 
Anyway I guess my main confusion stems from the fact that my gut feeling is that `switchMap` should make the observable hot, which it apparently does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to remove the multiple invocations by doing

```
const httpResultStream = combinedTriggerStream
   .switchMap(v => simulateHttp('http ' + v, 3000))
   .share();
```

Still not sure why I need this.

Also I found this article quite helpful even though it didn't pertain to my question https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/

Comment: The `share` operator makes your observable "hot", which basically means the stream is shared between subscribers. Lots of articles about it on the web, for instance [this one](https://alligator.io/rxjs/hot-cold-observables/).

Comment: @Jeto thanks for the interesting link. I did some more digging and it really seems to be caused by having mulitple subscribers. Performing  `map` didn't seem to make any difference even though I could have sworn that I have seen the multiple invocations of the http call after adding it.